# How do I create a nuget package from a managed C++ library?

Tags: c++, .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a library written in native c++, and then a second library which links to the first in managed c++ (sorry if I am misusing terms, hopefully you get what I am talking about). I can build both, and the second I can reference from my .net application and use perfectly fine. I want to pack the second into a nuget package.

What is the process for this? Linked tutorials or other answers are wonderful, though I feel like I have tried them all and run into problems or they are for different use cases. I'd prefer to do this by the command line using `msbuild` as I want to make this part of our github workflow, but I'd settle for doing this in visual studio so I can have some semblance of a victory and mental respite.

This is for .Net Framework 4.7.2 (not in my control)

Thanks!

Comment: A better way to approach this would be to take one of the better tutorials and walk through it, pointing out where you're running into problems or confusion and asking about those problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached this from a different angle and built the libraries normally and then packaged the dll's into a nuget package using the Nuget CLI rather then the `msbuild pack` functionality.

This was the [tutorial](https://thewissen.io/packaging-legacy-dlls-nuget/) I referenced.

You need to make a relatively simple .nuspec file specifying which DLLs to package and then you can simply run the pack command like so:

`nuget.exe pack my-file.nuspec`